# regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of VAT numbers. The problem is, some of them contain two character country ISO code in the beginning, others do not. I need to strip those 2 letters if they exist, for example, es7782173x becomes 7782773x and 969652255801 remains the same.
Please help me with the regular expression.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily call for regular expressions.

Comment: Probably quicker to do a simple string check to see if the first char isn't numeric, then extract a substring if it is. regex would be fewer lines of code, but the usual proviso holds: any problem whose solution calls for a regex now has two problems.

Comment: Here is a nice tool to experiment with your regex.

http://rubular.com/

Comment: Marc, I think the actual point of this phrase was to avoid using too much regex and not to avoid using them at all. In this project, that is a huge one, one can hardly find any regex whatsoever. So a small and simple one would not make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PHP regex to replace all letters from the beginning:

```
$vat = 'es7782173x';
$vat = preg_replace('/^\D+/', '', $vat);
```

`\D` matches anything that is not a digit, and replacing it with the empty string `''` effectively strips it from the beginning (`^` anchor). `+` matches 1 or more occurrences.

Comment: Deleted my answer since it was essentially the same as yours, might be worth mentioning this also works with an array as input, and it will return an array as output in that case. So no need to loop and preg_replace each entry in a list.